# Website first load sometimes very slow

Tags: php, performance

I'm experiencing a weird error on one of the my websites www.scr-t.com, which loads really slow but only sometimes on the first load. I've tried removing elements from the website and checked domain settings and everything, but I just can't figure out what could be wrong.

Website is on a custom PHP CMS I've made, but that same CMS is used on 20 other websites that work just fine.

If anyone of you had similar problems, please help me with ideas.

Many thanks!

Comment: "Same problems with your custom CMS"?? Do you have some server logs?

Comment: Maybe some things are stored in a cache and it takes time to build the cache?

Comment: +1 for the cache, and u r using a bit much outer resources, like youtube and FB (these were the ones on first sight). And some of the other options are if u r resizing the images with CSS & HTML etc.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks ok besides large index file and some png files: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/bg8URp/http://www.scr-t.com/

if you want to speed up your website use: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights

Answer (score 0):

Move all your Javascript to bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

I'll not open that link because I don't trust ads.

But..
You could check how many resources are served, for example how many images, scripts, css styles.

Usually you could minify them, place many small images in sprites, compress css all in one file and also do that with the scripts, and maybe place them in a cdn to help parallelizing the download. This if your first time loading is due too many files being downloaded and not parallelizable, you could double check disabling caching on your browser (usually browsers developer tools offer that or check your settings).

Also be sure to set long expire tags or ETA tags on static cacheable resources.

Also you could check if your site is doing too much work when it sees a new user but it is too much dependant on your code to have good advices here.